# Product price excl tax in order histroy info page (Opencart 1.5.6.4)

Tags: opencart, tax

Is there a simple way to show the price without tax instead of incl on the order histroy page in opencart 1.5.6.4? I Managed to "fix" it everywhere else.

[Screendump opencart 1.5.6.4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeBA1.png)

Can anybody tell me how to change this?

Thank you!

Comment: Edit the file ```/catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/order_info.tpl``` (maybe you will have to change the **/default/** part with the name of the theme you are using).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <file name="catalog/controller/account/order.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA['price'    => $this->currency->format($product['price'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? $product['tax'] : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA['price' => $this->currency->format($product['price'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA['total'    => $this->currency->format($product['total'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? ($product['tax'] * $product['quantity']) : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA['total'    => $this->currency->format($product['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Done :)